# Managing asynchronous communication: how to examine response received in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, producer-consumer

I have a dispatcher thread and a listener thread. When I dispatch a command, I want to wait for response before I send follow up command. Moreover I need to examine the respond before I can proceed with 2nd command, the least of which is to confirm the response is received and everything is okay. My pseudo code is below:

```
void MainWindow::downloadData()
{
    dispatcher->getInfo(); // sends command

    // QString response = receiver->response() // idealy I would like to check response but since its async, i can't really do that!

    dipatcher->askData(); // the 2nd command and so forth

}
```

Is there any elegant way to solve this issue? The only way I can think of is if I use the same thread and all calls are blocking but that's not necessarily a good solution.

In Qt, I could use signals and slots to connect them in cascading manner so when the first signal is triggered it initiates the whole sequence of operation (each slot emitting a new signal) but seems rather dirty as well.

Comment: It's event-driven programming. It could be clean if you do it right.

Comment: @user3528438 Lets say I am issuing three commands when user press a button to accomplish something. If I wire each command to signal and slot which will establish a chain of events, that seems rather cumbersome. The commands are low level and they are better independent. I feel like rest of the system should use the commands,the command shouldn't dictate what happens next!?

Comment: The dispatcher/listener thread split is unnecessary. It can all be handled from one thread. You need a request object, or a request handler object that issues signals when the result of a request is available. This can then guide a `QStateMachine` whose states issue further requests. Parts of the state machine can be automatically generated - say, suppose that you have a list of requests to issue without doing special processing between them - you can generate the needed states programmatically.

Comment: You don't need multiple threads if you're processing sequentially. You can also just add all commands to a queue and process them from the front until the queue is empty.

Comment: I am using `QTcpServer` derived class and its `listen()` function, it just listens on a port so I should use `listen()` when I need it and `close` when I am am done listening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most robust ways to handle asynchronous events and process a chains/graphs of actions upon these events are FSMs. Qt provides a basis for implementing FSMs with its [Qt-State machine framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine.html). I'd suggest to go this way. Unfortunately all the examples provided by Qt for FSM are dealing with GUIs and animations.

The advantage of FSM approach is, FSMs can be represented both as graphs and as tables. The first option is great for understanding, the second for validation, that there are no endless loops and "dead" ends.

I've built on basis of Qt-FSM framework own framework for defining FSMs in a domain specific language. I use it for controlling a complex machine having couple of sensors actors all working asynchronously. Using DSL helps me to implement in higher abstraction - in the abstraction level of FSM-graphs.